# Xcode Canvas not showing me the entire page and just segments

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Apps")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        Image("utm")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
        Text("UTM")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        Text("Virtual machines for macOS")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        Button("Get UTM") {
            
        }
            .background(Color(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.861, brightness: 1.0))
            .controlSize(.large)
            .cornerRadius(25)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And when I open canvas, this happens:
[image]
How do I turn it into 1 single content view instead of all of the segments being split up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, in SwiftUI, views should be encapsulated within stack structures, like the example provided below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Apps")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Image("utm")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            Text("UTM")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Text("Virtual machines for macOS")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            Button("Get UTM") {
                
            }
                .background(Color(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.861, brightness: 1.0))
                .controlSize(.large)
                .cornerRadius(25)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).